# Why requests are forbidden from Google URL Shortener

Tags: google-url-shortener

```
@staticmethod
def _google_url_shortener(original_url):
    try:
        data = json.dumps({'longUrl': original_url})
        result = requests.post(conf.GoogleURL, headers={
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, data=data)
        shortened_url = result.json()['id']
        return shortened_url
    except Exception as e:
        print('err {}'.format(e))
        return original_url
```

I am using Google URL Shortener to make my URLs shorter, from google, it says **1,000,000 requests per day**, unfortunately,  I got 403 ERROR after 2500+ requests have been sent out. It doesn't help even I drop the request TPS to 0.5

Can anyone help?

[image]

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31662921/google-url-shortener-api-error-403-forbidden-update) relevant?

Comment: @raina77ow Thanks for your post. I have checked my API Key and it's unrestricted, here it is `This key is unrestricted. To prevent unauthorized use and quota theft, restrict your key.
Key restriction lets you specify which web sites, IP addresses, or apps can use this key`